# Unable to get user's location in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

Please help, I cannot get the user's location:
Imagine I have a widget like:

```
 Text('LAT: ${_currentPosition?.altitude ?? "na"}'),
            Text('LNG: ${_currentPosition?.longitude ?? "na"}'),
            Text('ADDRESS: ${_currentAddress ?? "na"}'),
            const SizedBox(height: 32),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _getCurrentPosition,
              child: const Text("Get Current Location"),
```

and the logic to get location through libraries:

```
  Future<bool> _handleLocationPermission() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Location services are disabled. Please enable the services')));
      return false;
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Location permissions are denied')));
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.')));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentPosition() async {
    final hasPermission = await _handleLocationPermission();

    if (!hasPermission) return;
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() => _currentPosition = position);
      _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition!);
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getAddressFromLatLng(Position position) async {
    await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude)
        .then((List<Placemark> placemarks) {
      Placemark place = placemarks[0];
      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
            '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.subAdministrativeArea}, ${place.postalCode}';
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }
```

which is inside a StatefulWidget.
I am currently getting nothing from it and I do not understand, since I am exactly following this tutorial:

https://medium.com/@fernnandoptr/how-to-get-users-current-location-address-in-flutter-geolocator-geocoding-be563ad6f66a

----------EDIT-------------

I tried to implement this with location package:

```
Location location = Location();
late bool _serviceEnabled;
late PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
late LocationData _locationData;
late double? fieldLatitude;
late double? fieldLogitude;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getfieldlocation();
  }

  Future<void> getfieldlocation() async {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    setState(() {
       fieldLatitude = _locationData.latitude;
       fieldLogitude = _locationData.longitude;
      print(fieldLatitude);print(fieldLogitude);
    });
  }
```

but it gives me an error related with initialization variables "Field fieldLatitude has not been initialized"

Comment: Instead of using late double? fieldLatitude;  Use Var fieldLatitude; also for fieldLongitude , value is always in double. So no probs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Understand your problem. In my project I am using https://pub.dev/packages/location package. Steps to be followed for getting location.

```
Future<void> getfieldlocation() async {
    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    setState(() {
      fieldLatitude = _locationData.latitude;
      fieldLogitude = _locationData.longitude;
      print(fieldLatitude);print(fieldLogitude);
    });
  }
```

I have called this in initstate() function which only calls at start.
If you want to call it continuously
Use **setduration** function.

If it works don't forget to contribute,or if having any doubts give a reply.
Have a Good Day : )

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Please see my edit I tried what u said